# How to parse the value to float?

Tags: c#, string

Code:

```
float rt = float.Parse("12.50%");
```

I am getting the error message as

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

How to parse a value to float?

Comment: remove the "%" symbol from the string before parsing

Comment: Remove % as float.Parse("12.50")

Comment: You forget `c#-5.0` tag

Answer (score 4):

It's the `%` which is causing a problem here. Either use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) with a custom pattern, or strip the `%` before you parse.

You should also be aware of cultural context - will the input *always* use `.` as the decimal separator, or do you need to use the locale of the supplier of the value? For example, in some locales this would be represented as "12,50%".

Answer (score 3):

```
float rt = float.Parse("12.50%".Replace("%",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to '%' sign in 12.50%

pasring is done in the same way you did it or,

`float.TryParse` also you can use .